# SSIS Script Task Error in Azure PAAS Server: The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: ssis

I'm working on a SSIS project using SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools) with Visual Studio 2015 and I'm referencing the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll in a Script Task and I have deployed the project through Azure Dev Ops(Pipeline and Release model) but it keeps throwing the following message:

**Script Task: Error - The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'(Are you missing an assembly reference?)**

I am not sure how to map the dlls inside the TFS.

I have also tried below approach as well but it didn't work out. Because there is no concept of drive concept in PAAS. So need to know how we can give the dlls reference inside the SSIS script task.

```
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
     static ScriptMain()
     {
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
     }
     static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
     {
         if (args.Name.Contains("ssisHelper"))
         {
             string path = @"c:\temp\";
             return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "ssisHelper.dll"));
         }
         return null;
     }
```

Any help please?

Comment: You need to add the dlls to GAC using gacutil. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes there is an issue with Interop DLL, so tried with different dlls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The office automation DLLs are part of an installation of Microsoft Office (licensing is also part of this install).

If you can install software on that box, you'll need to do so. Otherwise, you won't be able to use the office automation with your SSIS package

Comment: Yes there is an issue with Interop DLL, so tried with different dlls.